# Any way to edit .htaccess more efficiently?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I keep adding product pages to a website, with each product page set containing a `page.php` file, and another 3 ajax files (`a-page1.php`, `a-page2.php`)

and so, each product page:

1. is called for example: `page1.php`, `page2.php`.
2. contains 3 links to the ajax files:

a. `folder/page1/subfolder-a/`

b. `folder/page1/subfolder-b/`

c. `folder/page1/subfolder-c/`

(with everything constant excpet the digit).

Currently, each time I manually edit the `.htaccees` in order to make the links more pretty:

```
RewriteRule ^nice-name-for-page1/?$ page1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^folder/page1/subfolder-a/?$ /jump/a-page1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/page1/subfolder-b/?$ /jump/b-page1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/page1/subfolder-c/?$ /jump/c-page1.php [L]
```

Is there any way to automate this process, maybe have some interface where I can simply type in the `nice-name-for-page1` value, or take it from the PHP page itself (the canonical URL), and also have all the other 3 links ready simply by typing just the `page1` value?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using capture groups, something like

```
RewriteRule ^folder/page(\d+)/subfolder-([^/])/?$ /jump/$2-page$1.php [L]
```

so you only need a single entry in your .htaccess file for all page numbers and subfolders?

Comment: Actually `RewriteRule ^folder/page(\d+)/subfolder-([^/])/?$ /jump/$2-page$1.php [L]`

Comment: The first capture group `(\d+)` captures the digits as part of the `page` reference in the URL, and that becomes `$1`; the second capture group ([^/]) captures all characters between `subfolder-` and the next `/` character, and that becomes `$2`. These values are then substituted in the rewrite string in place of `$1` and `$2`

Answer (score 0):

We did this recently, albeit in .net, but the principle is still the same.  We made a single page the "details/content/product" page if you will.

We then added database fields into the table which would hold all of the product details and most importantly, the friendly url slug.

We then wrote the code to look at the URL being sent to the controller and then matched it up in the database.  For example:

```
http://testbetasite.azurewebsites.net/Products/Apple-iPhone-6-Plus
```

The code would look for the slug:

```
Apple-iPhone-6-Plus
```

and look it up in the database where ProductSlug == "Apple-iPhone-6-Plus" and would then grab the field containing the images, content, price, etc. and display it in the page.  Instant friendly URLs' without needing to access the htaccess or rewrite rules.

Now again, we did this because the client will be managing this and we wanted it to be easy for them to assign their own friendly URLs.

I can help you with doing this in PHP, but if it's not the direction you want to go, I can completely understand.  Just let me know.

Comment: This sounds kinda like what I'm looking for, though I'm not sure I understand what does it require. to use a MySQL database? so basically everything is done on the same page and thus there's no need for .htaccess? I currently don'y have such a database, does it effect the processing speed significantly? and what about the 3 links though?

Comment: If you don't have a database, you may want to consider some type of flat file data source such as an XML file or something (if you are going to have several products in your application).  However, given you are using PHP and MySQL is a free database (for the most part), I'd highly recommend looking into using it.  It's really pretty easy these days to hook one up to PHP and get it all talking together.

Comment: For your three links I'd imagine something like one page called product.php.  With a little PHP MVC you could do something very similar to what I was describing above.  Gathering from your question, it seems as though you are trying to avoid having to create multiple folders for your application's products and have a more dynamic system.  However, the answer given above by Mark Baker is a good one which does answer your question.  I just always try to understand more about what the final goal is of your application.